# crear un arreglo dinamico con la funcion $.map en jquery

Tags: jquery

He adjuntado mi código.

Lo que tengo en mi grilla una columna orden, esta columna tiene un `combobox` ("ninguno,1,2,3,4"), cada vez que selecciono un `combobox` repetido es decir con el mismo valor me lanzara un mensaje que ese orden ya ah sido seleccionado, para ello se almaceno en un array para buscar los elementos repetidos, luego el segundo caso es cuando mi `combobox` este con un valor ya seleccionado y deseo editarlo.

**Ejemplo:** `combobox` con valor "2" y deseo cambiarlo a valor "4" , el valor 2 anterior sera reemplazado por el nuevo valor "4", y todo ese cambio se vera reflejado en el array, siempre y cuando el valor no se ha repetido, y una vez que el array este listo se mostrara en el `textbox` que se encuentra en la parte inferior, bueno gracias esa es mi consulta.

- en el combobox deberia aparecer por defecto "ninguno", pero no me hace caso.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var myarray = [];


            var countries = { '0': 'Ninguno', '1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4' };
            var states = { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii', '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' };
            var statesOfCountry = {
                1: { '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida', '4': 'Hawaii' },
                2: { '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford' }
            };
            var mydata = [
                { id: '0', orden: '1', State: '1', Name: "Louise Fletcher" },
                { id: '1', orden: '1', State: '3', Name: "Jim Morrison" },
                { id: '2', orden: '2', State: '5', Name: "Sherlock Holmes" },
                { id: '3', orden: '2', State: '6', Name: "Oscar Wilde" }
            ];

            var grid = jQuery("#list");
          
            grid.jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: 'local',
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Name', width: 800 },
                    {
                        name: 'orden', width: 80, editable: true,
                        edittype: 'select',
                        editoptions: {
                            value: countries
                            , defaultValue: "0",
                            dataEvents: [
                                {
                                    type: 'change',
                                    fn: function (e, rowid) {

                                        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow");
                                        /*var rowid = row.attr('title');*/

                                        var rowcodigo = row.attr('id');

                                        var v = parseInt($(e.target).val());
                                    
                                        myarray.push(v);

                                        validateArray = getDistinctArray(myarray);

                                        document.getElementById("num_orden").value = validateArray;

                                        function getDistinctArray(arr) {
                                            var compareArray = new Array();


                                            if (arr.length >= 1) {
                                                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                   
                                                    if (compareArray.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
                                              
                                                        compareArray.push(arr[i]);
                                                    } else {


                                                   
                                                        alert("el numero orden " + arr[i] + " para noticias en español ya existe");
                                                        //elimina el numero orden existente en el array
                                                        arr.splice(arr[i]);
                                                 
                                                        $("select#" + rowcodigo + "_orden").prop('selectedIndex', 0);



                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            return compareArray;
                                        }


                                        var valor_actual = $("select#" + rowcodigo + "_orden").val();
                                        alert(valor_actual);

                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },

                    },
                  
                ],
        
                ondblClickRow: function (id, ri, ci) {
                 
                  grid.editRow(id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', null,
                                 function (rowid, response) {  // aftersavefunc
                                    // grid.setColProp('State', { editoptions: { value: states } });
                                 });
                  //  return;
                },
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                sortname: 'Name',
                height: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                pager: '#pager',
                caption: "Demonstrate dependend select/dropdown lists (edit on double-click)"
            }); //.navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
        });
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.uedsc.com/jquery/1.8.0/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.uedsc.com/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.uedsc.com/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="list"></table>
        <input type="text" id="num_orden" value=""/>
```

Comment: cuando cambias el array de dodne salen el 60, 50 etc ? ademas de que tipo sera el array porque si defines 60:1 seria una cadena? en ese caso seria un ["60:1", "50:2"]

Comment: gracias por responder, si tengo una tabla con filas (con una columna id), en cada fila hay un combobox , en el evento onchange del combobox deseo atrapar el valor del combobox y tomar el id de la fila y formar un array ejemplo: 1 (valor del id)=>2(valor del combobox), etc, y una vez formado necesito extraer sus valores, alguna idea de como hacer esto?, gracias

Comment: Para poder responderte hay que reproducir lo que tienes hecho ya. Edita la pregunta e incluye el código que haz escrito con la tabla, los combobox y el evento `onchange`

Comment: Ya enviado mi codigo y editado mi pregunta para ser mas precisa, gracias ojala alguna idea..